# Cause makefile to error if an environment variable is not set?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, virtualenv, gnu-make

I'd like my makefile to crash if an environment variable is not set. This is what I have so far:

```
ifneq ($(shell echo $${VIRTUAL_ENV:+True}),True)
$(error Looks like no virtualenv is active)
endif
```

and it works!

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this, perhaps with make directly instead of calling `$(shell ...)`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [`origin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#The-origin-Function) function...

```
ifeq ($(origin VIRTUAL_ENV),undefined)
$(error Looks like no virtualenv is active)
endif
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that environment vars are implicitly "imported" into make's namespace which is why this answer works: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment. It's also worth pointing the OP to the documentation for `origin`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html#Origin-Function

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplest option, but isn't as fine tuned as using `origin`.

```
ifndef VIRTUAL_ENV
$(error Looks like no virtualenv is active)
endif
```

One caveat here is that you can't distinguish if `VIRTUAL_ENV` defined in the Makefile or in the environment.

As @KurtisRader pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559638/cause-makefile-to-error-if-an-environment-variable-is-not-set/64578959#comment114187915_64559987), this is possible because environment vars are implicitly "imported" into make's namespace https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html.